# Can I run TFS Build Controller and Unit Tests on one machine and TFS Build Agents on another machine?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have sucessfully setup two machines. The first machine uses as TFS Build Controller and the other machine use as TFS Build Agent.

There are two things I want to do.

1. Run SQL scripts on TFS Build Controller machine. I have all SQL script files on TFS but I have no idea how can I get it run.
2. I want to do is upload the output (dll and exe files) from TFS Build Agent machine back to TFS Build Controller machine then run test on this machine. (I want to run test after I run all sql script files)

Please let me know if this is possible or not. You can just give me a link since I know it might take a long explanation. I would appriciate if you could write down the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is all possible, but I would strongly suggest not using the Build Controller for that.  Build Controllers are meant to just dole the builds out to the Agents that do all the work.  Also Build Controllers are typically shared between Team Projects, so if a single Team Project is abusing the Controller it can affect others; whereas Build Agents are usually dedicated to Team Projects.  You should be able to run your SQL Scripts and tests on the Build Agent, that's what most people will do.

Having said that, if you're set on still doing it, you can modify the build workflow template to accomplish it. Anything inside the Run On Agent activity runs on the Build Agent, anything outside of that runs on the Build Controller.  See Ewald's Blog series on customizing TFS Build if you've never done it before: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx

Comment: The link in your answer does help me A LOT. Thanks!